# SmtpJS - Send Email with embed images

Tags: javascript, email, smtp, smtpjs

Sample from https://smtpjs.com/ only shows how to send text and attachments. What I need is to embed image as part of the email.

```
Email.send({
Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
  Username : "username",
  Password : "password",
  To : 'them@website.com',
  From : "you@isp.com",
  Subject : "This is the subject",
  Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
    message => alert(message)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently **Body** works like html scripts so it is possible to embed image with stmpjs by just adding  with image path instead of adding images as attachment.

Table is still the preferred choice than using div. Can't seems to get css to work on most email app.

```
Email.send({
    SecureToken : "***********",
    To : emailaddress,
    From : "noreply@****.com",
    Subject : "Title",
    Body : `<div align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><img src='imgurl' width="100%"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%"></td>
            <td><a href="link" target="_blank"><img src='imgurl' width="100%" /></a>
            </td>
            <td width="30%"></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>`,
}).then(
    message => console.log("mail sent successfully")
);
```